# Write file to memory and get an url pointing to it

Tags: c#, file, memory, chm

I have a single *.exe file program and a *.chm help file.

I have embedded the help file as a resource in my exe and now I want to open it so that the user can see the help.

As far as I know the only way to do that would be to use the HelpProvider class, but it only accepts an url as the address of a file. So I *have* to write my resource *.chm file somewhere and give its address to the provider.

However I don't want to write the file to disk, so I thought I'd just use `MemoryStrem` or something and write it in memory. But how would I go about getting an url to that file in memory?

Comment: Why have you embedded the file as a resource?

Comment: @ChrisBint - indeed!

Comment: @ChrisBint, I want to have just a single *.exe file. It is a firm requirement. Should I not have done it as an embedded resource?

Comment: You could probably embed a httpserver in your app and have it run and then you can have /helpfile or whatever return the resource but it seems a lot of hassle

Comment: @BugFinder, I thought embedding the chm would be as easy as `ShowHelp(this, Resources.MyHelpFile)` but, alas, I need an url to point somewhere and I REALLY want it to be to memory.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you will need to save the file to disk to open the .chm file.

An idea could be to host the uncompiled html , used with the .chm online, then open a browser to view it? the browser could be embedded into your application?
This will allow you to update the help content when required.